# R with postgresql database

Tags: r

I've been trying to query data from postgresql database (pgadmin) into R and analyse. Most of the queries work except when I try to write a condition specifically to filter out most of the rows. Please find the code below

```r
dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from "db_name"."User" where "db_name"."User"."FirstName" = "Mani" ')
```

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
>     Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  column "Mani" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...from "db_name"."User" where "db_name"."User"."FirstName" = "Mani" 
>                                                                         ^

this is the error I get, Why is it considering Mani as a column when it is just an element. Someone pls assist me

Answer (score 4):

String literals in Postgres (and most flavors of SQL) take *single* quotes.  This, combined with a few other optimizations in your code leave us with this:

```
sql <- "select * from db_name.User u where u.FirstName = 'Mani'"
dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

Note that introduced a table *alias*, for the `User` table, so that we don't have to repeat the fully qualified name in the `WHERE` clause.